# A Component responding to another components action

Tags: ember.js

I have two Ember components `my-select` and `my-button`, when a user selects an options from `my-select` I need to update the `my-button` component. Both components currently live inside the same template, what is the correct way to fire an action from the `my-select` component that the `my-button` component can listen to and then update?

Answer (score 2):

The parent component should give down an action to the `my-select` component and then update a state that is given down to the `my-button` component.

Thats what people call DDAU, *Data down Actions up*.

Like this:

*.hbs*

```
{{my-select onsomething=(action 'onsomething')}}
{{my-button data=data}}
```

*.js*

```
actions: {
  onsomething(dataFromSelect) {
    this.set('data', dataFromSelect);
  }
}
```